# Passing query strings to $routeParams to filter and persist a collection of items

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have been playing around with the $location service in angular, with trying to pass certain values to $routeParams to filter a set of items based on multiple conditions like colour, style, category and so forth

My API has a set of filters it can manipulate a group of objects by and one is 'IN' so for example if I want the the API to only return Blue, Red & Green I can do the following:

```
filter[]=product_colours,in,red,blue,green
```

If i wanted to just get a certain set of styles in them colours I can do

```
filter[]=product_colours,in,red,blue,green&filter[]=product_sub_category,in,Long,Short,Slim
```

I have put together a CodePen trying to prototype my idea of filtering:

CodePen example: http://codepen.io/sutsurikeru1986/pen/YqaeeO

What I am trying to do, but I am having issues with, is trying to maintain the values passed to the query string using &location.search() to be maintained after a page refresh and passing such values to $routeParams so my route can understand the it - as well as preventing the query string from becoming:

```
?key=param1&key=param2&key=param3
```

Instead of something a little cleaner like:

```
?key=param1-param2-param3
```

Any help to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I use this process to save a state object to HTML5 local storage when the page is refreshed or closed. Then I reload the state in the controller (or a factory if you wish) when the page reloads.

```
// get the state object from local storage
$scope.state = angular.fromJson(localStorage.getItem(id));

// make sure state is an object
$scope.state = (angular.isObject($scope.state)) ? $scope.state : {};

// update your route params in the state object
$scope.state.selectors = $routeParams.selectors;

// when the page refreshes or is closed angular broadcasts a "$destroy" message
$scope.$on("$destroy", function() {

    // save the route to html5 local storage
    localStorage.setItem("some_state_id", angular.toJson($scope.state));
});
```

Comment: If the user hasn't visited with a certain query string combination, won't i need to to store this in locaalstorage then use it in the controller?

Comment: For a default case you could use angular.merge({}, $scope.state.selectors, default_selectors);

Where default_selectors is some object with fields representing default colors.